# eloquent return two columns all records

Tags: laravel-4, eloquent

I'm sure this is very simple - I just need two columns from a country database to populate a `<select>`

Looking at this URL I came up with the code below, but this seems to return an object for each record

http://laravel.com/api/class-Illuminate.Database.Eloquent.Model.html#_all

```
class countries extends Eloquent
{




}

public static function getCountrySelect()
{

        return countries::all(array("name","iso_3166_2"));


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to populate custom field from database use this:->

```
 countries::lists('name','iso_3166_2');
         i.e
 countries::lists('coulmnname1','coulmnname2');
```

and if you want to get suppose first 10 entries for that model use this:

```
 countries::take(10)->get();
```